# Netbeans IDE trouble

Tags: netbeans, configuration, ide

I have just installed Netbeans on a Windows 8 computer and it seems to work (mostly) correct. When I try to run a C program I have created in the  IDE (to debug), it compiles without error but during the run phase returns the message ... "Cannot find /tmp, please create". I thought this might be a permissions problem but couldn't see anything out of joint there. Any advice? Anyone run into this problem?

Comment: What compiler are you using for `C`? The problem is mostly the installation. Please recheck the installation

Comment: I am using a cygwin installation.

Comment: (https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10011), this might help